# Traversing rows of one table and using Cursor for selecting values based on the value of that row of first table in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to traverse the rows (containing only one column) which are extracted by the first select statement then by using the values of that row I want to execute the select statement. But the issue here is my first select statement returns three rows and it could be more depending the situation. But when it reaches to the main select statement, it says "**an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement**"

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TAJTEST

   ( CapRefCursor OUT CAP_CUR_PKG.CapCur)

IS

/******************************************************************************
   NAME:       TAJTEST
   PURPOSE:     Testing Multiple lessee selection

   REVISIONS:
   Ver        Date        Author           Description
   ---------  ----------  ---------------  ------------------------------------
   1.0        05/08/2013   Tajamul Iqbal       1. Created this procedure.

   NOTES:

******************************************************************************/





 V_APPLICANTTYPE varchar2(5);

BEGIN      

DECLARE


   Cursor    c1 IS   select  fn_applicanttype(applicant_type.application_number,applicant_type.identification_code) as APPLICANTTYPE   from applicant_type where 
   applicant_type.application_number = 'A000000807000' ;                                                           

BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
        LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO V_APPLICANTTYPE;
      EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;                                

                         IF V_APPLICANTTYPE='IC'   then                                      

                           SELECT 'Individual' as App_Type,
                                             substr(APPLICANT_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER, 1, 10 ) as APPLICATION_NUMBER,
                                             APPLICANT_DETAIL.IDENTIFICATION_CODE,

                                            APPLICANT_DETAIL.APPLICANT_ID AS CUSTOMER_ID ,

                                            APPLICANT_DETAIL.FIRST_NAME AS NAME,
                                            APPLICANT_DETAIL.LESSEE_NO as LESSEE,
                                            APPLICANT_DETAIL.SHORT_NAME as shortname,
                                            APPLICANT_DETAIL.SSN_BUSS_ID as ssnBusinessID,
                                            APPLICANT_DETAIL.PAYMENT_DUE_DAY as paymentDueDay,
                                            APPLICANT_DETAIL.USE_TAX_EXEMPT_CDE as useTaxExemptCode,
                                            Applicant_Detail.remit_address as remittanceAddress,
                                            APPLICANT_TYPE.MAIN_APPLICANT ,
                                            APPLICANT_TYPE.APPLICANT_TYPE,
                                            ADDRESS.CITY,
                                            ADDRESS.STATE_CDE as state,    
                                            ADDRESS.UNIT_NO AS Address1, 
                                            ADDRESS.POST_CODE_2 as zipCode,                            
                                            contract_detail.LP_PORTFOLIO as Portfolio,                            
                                            contract_detail.LP_COMPANY AS company,                            
                                            contract_detail.LP_REGION AS region,                            
                                            contract_detail.LP_OFFICE AS office                              
                                            FROM  APPLICANT_DETAIL   INNER JOIN                              
                                            ADDRESS  on APPLICANT_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER= ADDRESS.APPLICATION_NUMBER                              
                                            and ADDRESS.ADDRESS_CODE=1 and address.identification_code=1                              
                                            INNER JOIN  CONTRACT_DETAIL  on APPLICANT_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER= CONTRACT_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER                                                           
                                            Inner Join Applicant_type on APPLICANT_TYPE.APPLICATION_NUMBER= APPLICANT_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER and   
                                            APPLICANT_TYPE.IDENTIFICATION_CODE= APPLICANT_DETAIL.IDENTIFICATION_CODE                                
                                            WHERE (APPLICANT_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER ='A000000807000');





                                   else if  V_APPLICANTTYPE='CL'   then

                                         SELECT  'Company' as App_Type,
                                                   substr(Company_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER, 1, 10 ) as APPLICATION_NUMBER,
                                                    Company_DETAIL.IDENTIFICATION_CODE,

                                                    Company_DETAIL.Lessee_No AS CUSTOMER_ID ,
                                                     APPLICANT_TYPE.MAIN_APPLICANT ,
                                                    APPLICANT_TYPE.APPLICANT_TYPE,
                                                    Company_DETAIL.Name AS NAME,
                                                    Company_DETAIL.LESSEE_NO as LESSEE,
                                                    Company_DETAIL.SHORT_NAME as shortname,
                                                    Company_DETAIL.SSN_BUSS_ID as ssnBusinessID,
                                                    Company_DETAIL.PAYMENT_DUE_DAY as paymentDueDay,
                                                    Company_DETAIL.USE_TAX_EXEMPT_CDE as useTaxExemptCode,
                                                    Company_DETAIL.remit_address as remittanceAddress,

                                                    ADDRESS.CITY,
                                                    ADDRESS.STATE_CDE as state,
                                                    ADDRESS.UNIT_NO AS Address1,
                                                    ADDRESS.POST_CODE_2 as zipCode,
                                                     contract_detail.LP_PORTFOLIO as Portfolio,
                                                     contract_detail.LP_COMPANY AS company,
                                                    contract_detail.LP_REGION AS region,
                                                    contract_detail.LP_OFFICE AS office

                                                  FROM Company_DETAIL         INNER JOIN  ADDRESS  on
                                                  Company_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER= ADDRESS.APPLICATION_NUMBER

                                                  and ADDRESS.ADDRESS_CODE=1 and address.identification_code=1
                                                  INNER JOIN  CONTRACT_DETAIL  on Company_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER= CONTRACT_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER
                                                  Inner Join Applicant_type on APPLICANT_TYPE.APPLICATION_NUMBER= COMPANY_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER and 
                                                  APPLICANT_TYPE.IDENTIFICATION_CODE= COMPANY_DETAIL.IDENTIFICATION_CODE
                                                  WHERE (Company_DETAIL.APPLICATION_NUMBER = 'A000000807000');
                       end if;

                       end if;

   END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;      

    END;
 END TAJTEST;
/
```

Please help me in this regard. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In a procedure or function you can't just `SELECT`; you have to `SELECT` *into* something, using one of the following:

- `SELECT table.col1, table.col2 INTO var1, var2 FROM ...`, *or*
- `OPEN <cursor> FOR SELECT table.col1, ...`

In this case you want the `OPEN <cursor> FOR SELECT...`, and the `OUT` parameter is the cursor you want to select into. For example, the first `SELECT` should start off as:

```
IF V_APPLICANTTYPE='IC'   then
  OPEN CapRefCursor FOR
    SELECT 'Company' as App_Type, ...
```

The second `SELECT` (after the `else if`) needs to do the same thing.

Comment: yeah , I have this if else logic working fine, the only issue is it says "an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement".. :(

Comment: I just updated my query with properly indentation .Now you may not be confused with if and else statements.

Comment: Tajamul, both your `SELECT` statements need to start with `OPEN CapRefCursor FOR`. For example, `OPEN CapRefCursor FOR SELECT  'Company' as App_Type, ...`. There may be other issues, but you're getting the "INTO clause" error because when you're in a procedure you can't just `SELECT`; you have to select *to* something. In your case you need to select into the `OUT` variable.

Comment: Yeah..........Thank you soooooooooo much...atlast I just solved it....  :)  Thank you.